# What does "has no metadata" mean in a yolk package listing?

Tags: virtualenv, pip, setuptools, virtualenvwrapper, yolk

After setting up a simple virtualenv and installing a few packages, when I `yolk -l` I get

```
Python          - 2.7.5        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
ipython         - 1.1.0        - active 
pip 1.5 has no metadata
readline        - 6.2.4.1      - active 
setuptools 2.1 has no metadata
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7)
yolk            - 0.4.3        - active
```

What does "has no metadata" mean for `pip` and `setuptools` (both, I believe, installed when the virtualenv is created)? Can I do something (e.g. with `pip`) to "fix" this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some (newer) Python packages store their package metadata in a different file than expected by yolk; [yolk3k](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk3k/) will knows how to handle that though. Just

```
pip install --upgrade yolk3k
```

Comment: This seems to be getting worse. I just uninstalled and re-installed a bunch of packages and now many more "have no metadata". Is this expected?

Comment: Try installing yolk3k instead of yolk.